# Second chart using chartjs does not display on site

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I have two charts but only the first one shows on website. I can even copy paste the first chart where the second chart is, and it will still not show.

My first chart:

```
<div class="main_body-child-table-barchart">
                        <canvas id="Chart"></canvas>
                            <script>
                            var ctx_2 = document.getElementById("Chart").getContext('2d');
                            var Chart = new Chart(ctx_2, {
                                type: 'bar',
                                data: {
                                  labels: <?php echo json_encode($arr_macd_dates_formated); ?>,
                                  datasets: [
                                    {
                                      label: '<?php echo $str_macd, $arr_macd_name[0]  ; ?>',
                                      backgroundColor: ["#faae00"],
                                      data: <?php echo json_encode($arr_macd_diff); ?>
                                    }
                                  ]
                                },
                                options: {
                                  legend: { display: false },
                                  title: {
                                    display: true,
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            </script>
                    </div>
```

My second chart:

```
<div class= "main_body-child-table-barchart_sma">
                        <div> <canvas id="barChart" width="600" height="400" ></canvas> </div>
                            <script>
                            var canvas = document.getElementById('barChart');
                            var ctx2 = canvas.getContext('2d');
                            var myChart_2 = new Chart(ctx2, {
                               type: 'line',
                               data: {
                                  labels: ["2010", "2011", "2012", "2013"],
                                  datasets: [{
                                     label: 'Dataset 1',
                                     data: [150, 200, 250, 150],
                                     color: "#878BB6",
                                  }, {
                                     label: 'Dataset 2',
                                     data: [250, 100, 150, 10],
                                     color: "#4ACAB4",
                                  }]
                               }
                            });

                            </script>
                    </div>
```

You can check the website out and see that data does go through, but graph does not show: https://signal-invest.com/tick/?ticker=aapl

Comment: You are including a `Chart.min.js'` in the page (note the right single quote, remove it).

Comment: Honestly, I didn't add that line and cannot find it in my code. But one chart shows while the second does not.

Comment: Use chrome devtools and the network pane, order by status, you will see that this file isn't  being loaded because of the typo (single quote). That affects other scripts in your site and is a possible cause.

Comment: I switched to Highcharts. Much easier man, no problems

Comment: It would be good for you learning to use the devtools panel on Chrome. These kids today have these awesome tools and still refuse to learn :)